# Dynamic select with Javascript Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, laravel, dynamic, html-select

I'm working on a project with Laravel 8, where I need to make a dynamic dropdown in a form to create categories. The first dropdown must show stores and the second one should show the categories of that store. I don't know if I should do this with javascript or some other way.

### Form:

```
<label for="store_id">Store</label>
<select id="store_id" name="store_id" class="custom-select">                 
@foreach($stores as $store)
   <option value="{{ $store->id}}">{{ $store->name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>

<label for="parent_category">Parent Category</label>
<select  id="parent_category" name="parent_category" class="custom-select">                                              
</select>
```

### Categories table

| id | store_id | parent_category_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

### Stores table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |

### CategoryController.php

```
public function create()
{              
  $stores = Store::all();
  $categories = Category::all();                    

  $data= [            
    'stores ' => $stores ,
    'categories ' => $categories 
  ];

return view('category.create')->with($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this approach with jQuery:

get store categories through relationship, depending on your relation type One to Many, Many to Many, etc:

```
public function Storecategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App/Models/Categories','store_id');
}
```

In your controller function and get store categories:

```
//return store categories with ajax response using relationship
$store_categories = StoreModel::find($store_id)->Storecategories()
//if any where clause you want to add
->where('Your conditions')
->get();

return response()->json(['store_categories'=>$store_categories->toArray() ]);
```

Send ajax request on selecting store, get categories array and create categories html dynamically:

```
//Perform action on selection of store
$(document).on('change','#store_id',function(){
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Your ajax url,
            data[store_id:stroe_id , _token:token],
            success: function (data) {
                let categories = data.store_categories;
                let html = '';
                $.each(categories ,function(i,v){
                    html += '<option value="'+v.id+'">'+v.name+'</option>';
                });
                $("#parent_category").html(html);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: The "public function Storecategories()" should be in Store Model, right? And I don't understand wich url should write in the Ajax Url.

Comment: yes relationship should be in store model

Comment: Thanks, and the Ajax Url field? I dont know what to write there.

Comment: create a route in `web.php` file and give it a path in an ajax url.

Comment: Route::post('`Your_cutom_path`', 'Your_Controller_Name@Controller_function_name');, give this path to ajax url.

Comment: I did all the steps, but still not working :(

Comment: can you please display error?

Comment: There is no error, the select's options are empty

Comment: did you receiving any data in the ajax success response?